Probability of First Record for General Distributions
Source: Feller's "An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications Volume II" Section I Problem 9

Show that if $X_j$ are positive random variables with (continuous) distribution $F$, then the probability of the first record value occurring at the $n$th place with value $\leq x$ is given by $[n(n+1)]^{-1}F^{n+1}(x)$ and the distribution of the first record value being $\leq x$ is given by $F(x) - (1-F(x))\log(1-F(x)^{-1}.$

Attempt: For the first part, the probability of drawing $n+1$ balls with value $\leq x$ is given by $F^{n+1}(x)$. The probability of the maximum occurring at the $n$th spot and second highest record at the $0$th spot is given by $[n(n+1)]^{-1}$, so we arrive at the answer combining these two together. For the latter distribution, we just sum over all $n$:
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{F^{n+1}(x)}{n(n+1)} $$
If I differentiate twice, I arrive at a geometric series I know: $\sum F^n(x)=(1-F(x))^{-1}$. If I integrate this latter series twice with respect to $F(x)$, I get $F(x)-(1-F(x))\log(1-F(x))^{-1}$ which is the distribution of the first record value.
Question: The first part makes sense to me intuitively and I enjoyed thinking about it, but the latter probability just felt like mindless algebraic manipulation. Is there a more intuitive derivation of this distribution?
